# Convert a very Small number String to Decimal

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, decimal

I want to convert a very Small number to Decimal,

Lets Say

```
String secondsStr = 0;
Decimal secondsValue;
Boolean success = Decimal.TryParse(secondsStr, out secondsValue);
```

But the problem is I have the string representation of it, 3.24E-08

```
String secondsStr = 3.24E-08;
Decimal secondsValue;
Boolean success = Decimal.TryParse(secondsStr, out secondsValue);
```

It always return success as false.

How can I parse that to get 0.00000003244657 ?

Comment: How are you going to use the 'very small number'? If it is for display purposes, you could treat it as a string.

Comment: @Chris: By the way, the accepted answer in the proposed duplicate which suggests to use `NumberStyles.Float` does not work with the string above.

Comment: @Tim, I agree, NumberStyles.Float didn't worked for me where as NumberStyles.Any did

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Strange. In linqpad I run `Double.Parse("3.24E-08", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float)` and it works fine...

Comment: @Chris: I assume the current culture is responsible. So either use `NumberStyles.Any` as i have suggest below or use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as third argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73.aspx) with the `NumberStyles` argument:

```
var ok = Decimal.TryParse(secondsStr, NumberStyles.Any, null, out secondsValue);
```

I have used `NumberStyles.Any` which works.

> Indicates that all styles except AllowHexSpecifier are used. This is a
>   composite number style.

**Update**: if it works with `NulberStyles.Float` depends on the current culture. If it uses `.` as decimal separator it works. So you can also use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as third argument:

```
var ok = Decimal.TryParse(secondsStr, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out secondsValue);
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim, It works exactly the way I wanted..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Boolean c= decimal.TryParse("3.24E-08", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, null, out a);
```